# How can I hide/show html elements without losing initial CSS Styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm trying to fix a log-in form on a website. When the user clicks our log-in link, a Log In form shows up in the horizontal center of the screen. When the user clicks on "Forgot Password?", the log-in form is set to display:none and the Forgot Password form appears in its place. Now if the user clicks "Forgot Password?" then they click "Cancel", the Forgot Password form disappears and the Log-In form reappears. The problem exists when the Log-In form reappears. It is no longer horizontally centered in the screen, instead it aligns left.

I understand that I could toggle visibility, but I don't want the space to be there, I want it to be replaced with the new form. Yet display:none isn't helping much either because it loses some CSS.

Here's the HTML (To respect my employer's company, I replaced our links in the src or href attributes):
http://pastebin.com/f4HMpfLk

Here's the CSS:
http://pastebin.com/wdwp8TqM

Is there a way for me to toggle visibility of the initial form, without losing the styling? Or is there a way I can keep it centered? I'm open to trying better ways of doing this. Thanks

PS: I tried changing document.getElementById('LoginWindow').style.display = 'inline-block'; to flex, which did center the window, but the contents within the div align left, and I lose CSS styling on the contents.

Comment: Post a complete code example *in your question* please.

Comment: What 'CSS Styling' do you actually loose? Why/How?

Comment: @fast if I use 'document.getElementById('LoginWindow').style.display = 'flex' ' I lose the input widths, as well as the alignment of everything within the log-in window. When I try to adjust for this using javascript, showRecoverPasswordForm() stops working. If i use style.display = 'none' then when the log in form reappears, the window is aligned horizontal left instead of remaining in the center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply because when you re-show the login form, you set it's display style to `inline-block`, which doesn't work with auto margins.

Set the display to `block` instead, which is the default for a `<div>` (and what it will be before you hide it) and all will be well.

```
  function showRecoverPasswordForm() {
    document.getElementById('recover-password').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('LoginWindow').style.display='none';
  }

function hideRecoverPasswordForm() {
    document.getElementById('recover-password').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('LoginWindow').style.display = 'block';
  }
```

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/h94zLhwa/3/

Comment: wow I feel so stupid. It's amazing how sometimes it's the little things that can completely make or break a site. As code gets longer, I tend to overlook the little things. Thank you very very much for your answer, it solved my problem.

Comment: No probs! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the z index, you can choose to put one object over the other in the same position by having a higher z index than the other object. Below is an example.

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
img2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: I was considering this but would my "hidden" javascript buttons still be clickable? I don't want users to accidentally submit a form even though the button isn't visible to the layer

Comment: What you could do to avoid this is make the entire button clickable and have the other one hidden underneath it, that way there is no chance of that happening. Use an <a></a> tag or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just changing the `display` property, you can change the CSS class of the login form and use two classes :

```
myOriginalClass {
    [CSS to show the login form]
}

myHiddenClass {
    [CSS to hide the login form]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign new CSS when the cancel button is clicked instead of just using show and hide. You can hide the login initially and then bring it back with whatever CSS you need. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#cancel_button').click(function(event) {
        $('#login_area').css("display","inline-block");//for example
      });

    });
```

If you need to add more than one CSS value, then try it like this:

```
$('#login_area').css({
   'display' : 'inline-block',
   'width' : '30px',
   'height' : '10px'
});
```

Or...if you have the CSS already defined for the login box, you can do this:

```
$('#login_area').addClass( "login_css" );
```

where you already have the class defined elsewhere like this:

```
login_css{
  display:inline;
 font-weight:bold;
}
```